# C# Downloading a file and uploading the same file as stream throws SocketException

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpclient

I'm trying to reupload some files. And to do so I'm getting the download stream and wrapping it with a StreamContent. Then trying to upload that stream. But I'm always getting `SocketException`. Am I missing anything here? Is it even possible to redirect on stream to another place?

```cs
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(fileDownloadInfo.Url);

var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(fileUploadUrl, streamContent);   // throws excepiton
```

Here's the full exception message:

```json
"InnerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.IO.IOException",
        "Message": "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
            "Message": "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": null,
            "HelpURL": null,
            "StackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            "ExceptionMethod": null,
            "HResult": -2147467259,
            "Source": null,
            "WatsonBuckets": null,
            "NativeErrorCode": 10053
        },
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingWriteStream.<WriteAsync>g__WriteChunkAsync|2_0(HttpConnection connection, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.CopyFromBufferAsync(Stream destination, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.CopyToContentLengthAsync(Stream destination, UInt64 length, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.CompleteCopyToAsync(Task copyTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.<CopyAsync>g__DisposeSourceAsync|0_0(Task copyTask, Stream source)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146232800,
        "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can feed the download stream from your `GetStreamAsync(...)` directly into the upload `PostAsync(...)`. Just to debug, what happens if you download the stream to a memorystream (or save it to disk) so you can set a breakpoint and inspect its contents?

Comment: @mortb I can download it to a FilleStream and then upload the file no problem. I was wondering if I can just "bypass" a stream then I won't have worry about deleting the file or cleaning up memory.

Comment: Try with `MemoryStream`, then you will only cache the file to memory. As I said, I'm not sure whether it is possible to directly feed the download stream into the upload